# Notification if something changed on parse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing

Is there a way that my app do something if a **string** was changed on **parse.com**. Like if I started the app and be on the main view the app shows a label which says that there is new information. Which actually can looked up in **another view**. Is there a way to get a message on a view, where the object of parse is **not** loaded. Any tips or suggestions would be helpful. 
Sorry but it seems that there is nothing at the internet about this topic. I thought I could make something with "if" but I didnt figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse.com doesn't support notifications to applications when data changes in their server. You will need to query the data on parse, compare with your local version of the data, and then show the label if the data is different.

You could probably abuse the Push Notifications service they offer to *sort of* hack this functionality in. When an application or user changes the data in Parse, as part of the save action in the client application could be to fire a "data changed" push notification. The iPhone app would then receive this notification and then be able to show the label. However, you will still have to support the query mechanism anyway as the notification method won't work correctly for users who don't authorise push notifications, and users who are not running the app at the time of receiving the notifications.

Comment: Thanks for you awnser it helped me a lot. However, if I want to show a new banner when the string on parse was changed could I use some thing like this: Set up a new string which is 1 on parse. Then make something in Xcode to show the banner if the number on parse isn't 1...after that the user can see the banner appearing at the start of the view once. And if the string = 1 theres no banner...Is that possible? Or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a possible solution. When you save the updated string set a flag - something like a "userHasSeen" flag. Then, the banner can interrogate this flag and decide to display or not. And if the user taps the banner (or whatever action they need to take to refresh their data) that action could reset the flag back to the "do not display" value. This would only work on a per user basis.

Comment: Sorry, but could you help me with this? I don't know how to do this...because I'm new to IOS programming and parse...